# Передать текст в PERL-скрипт

Tags: linux, perl

Всем привет. Такая проблема:
Есть perl-скрипт, в который можно передать данные из консоли:

```
./postinst.pl --nowizard --server=http://mysite.com --configdir=/etc/ocsinventory-agent --user=client --pass=feofh08f02jf2 --realm=OCS Inventory agent area --crontab --remove-old-linux-agent --debug --nossl --download --now
```

Но проблема в том, что в параметр --realm я подаю текст с пробелами, а он берет лишь первое слово, в итоге в конфиг записывает так:

realm=OCS

Как передать параметр так, чтобы взялась вся строка, а не только первое слово? (В кавычки брал - вообще пропускает этот параметр)

Если нельзя так передать, то как поменять сам PERL-скрипт? Сейчас он такой:

```
 }elsif($option=~/--realm=(\S*)$/){
$config->{realm} = $1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Печально, конечно, что обработка параметров сделана "вручную". Есть же стандартные либы, та же Getopt.

Но раз так написано, то значит передаем правильно, экранируя пробелы. Где-то так:

```
--realm=OCS\ Inventory\ agent\ area
```

Также в коде нужно сделать небольшую модификацию.

Поменяйте эту строку

```
$option=~/--realm=(\S*)$/
```

на такую

```
$option=~/--realm=(.*)$/)
```

После этого будет работать и в кавычках, и в двойных, и со слешами.

Comment: Не помогло :(

Comment: тогда нужно смотреть более прицельно в код. Кто его знает, как там разделяются параметры.

Comment:  }elsif($option=~/--realm=(\S*)$/){

    $config->{realm} = $1;
  }elsif($option=~/--tag=(\S*)$/){

    $config->{tag} = $1;
  }elsif($option=~/--crontab$/){

    $crontab = 1;
  }elsif($option=~/--get-old-linux-agent-config$/){

    $old_linux_config = 1;
  }elsif($option=~/--remove-old-linux-agent$/){

    $remove_old_linux = 1;
  }elsif($option=~/--debug$/){

Comment: Этот код понятен. Нужно чуточку выше, как получается `$option`

У меня есть подозрение, что там где то так

    my @opt = split / /, $command_line;
    for my $option (@opt) {
      # тут код с if
    }

Может скрипт покажете?

Comment:     for $option (@ARGV){
    # тут код с if
    }

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что разобрать @ARGV в разных системах с разными CLI не такое простое дело. Если вы выведете @ARGV на печать то увидите что ключи уже сформированы совсем не так как вы ожидали.
Почитайте тот-же [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.45/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#GetOptions_does_not_split_the_command_line_correctly)

Для корректной работы нужно "подготовить" @ARGV.
Как вариант:

```
    foreach my $param (@ARGV) {
        if ( $param =~ /^-/ ){
                if ( $param =~ /=/ ) {
                        ( $key, $value ) = split '=', $param;
                        $newArgv{$key} = $value;
                }else{
                        $newArgv{$param}++;
                }
        }else{
                $newArgv{$key} .= " $param";
        }

}
@ARGV = ();
for ( keys %newArgv ) {

        if ( $newArgv{$_} ){
                push ( @ARGV, $_."=".$newArgv{$_} );
        }else{
                push ( @ARGV, $_ );
        }
}
```

а потом уже по вкусу:

```
    use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
        "nowizard=i"         => \$nowizard,
        "server=s"         => \$server,
        "configdir=s"      => \$configdir,
        "user=s"           => \$user,
        "pass=s"           => \$pass,
        "realm=s"          => \$realm
);

print "Got values \$nowizard $nowizard \$server $server \$configdir $configdir \$user $user \$pass $pass \$realm $realm";
```

Answer (score 0):

> --realm='OCS Inventory agent area'

Comment: Я ж написал, что в кавычках он вообще не воспринимает такой параметр, как realm :(

Comment: $option=~/--realm=(\S*)$

тут явно указано что без пробелов брать

Comment: А можно как то поменять, чтоб брало с пробелами и в кавычках, например?
Я просто не особо силен в PERL.

Answer (score -1):

`print Dumper %ENV` и поглядеть в каких ключах лежат нужные данные, ну и юзать их.